# using spring ldap template how to manage to get ldap entry of dn stored in attribute of first found ldap entry without second ldap call

Tags: java, spring, active-directory, ldap, spring-ldap

In my Ldap Search using spring ldap template , I return a User object having one of the attributes that holds dn for another user. And , the User object has some attributes that needs to be populated with details obtained using the ldap entry of other user.

Without making a second ldap call , is it possible to get the first user's all attributes populated ?

Kindly help. I am left with no option but a second ldap call.

Let me know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept of "joins" in the LDAP world, so if you need to retrieve data from a referenced DN to populate more fields in your bean, that needs to happen using a separate call.